# How to efficiently sum multiple columns in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Recently I've started to use PySpark and it's DataFrames. I've got situation where I have around 18 million records and around 50 columns. I'd like to get a sum of every column so I use:

```
df_final = df.select([f.sum(c) for c in df.columns])
df_final.collect()
```

But my problem is that when I do it my whole code repartitions to only 1 partition and I've got problems with efficiency and not enough memory when I'm collecting.

I've read that it behaves this way because it needs to put every key of groupBy in single executor, since I'm summing whole column i actually don't need groupBy but i don't know how to achieve it otherwise.

Is there any more efficient/faster way to do it?

Comment: Your approach is correct. Everything ends up on the same partition eventually because the resulting dataframe only has one line. Yet, spark is based on the map reduce paradigm so it reduces lines that are already on the same partition before moving them around. In other words, your code should work. Could you provide the exception you obtain when running it?

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to apply collect() on small volumn of data as it is using too much memory. you can read [this article](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/19537/why-is-collect-using-way-too-much-ram.html) .

Instead of collect(), write the output into file.

```
df.write.csv('mycsv.csv')
```

**EDIT :**

- parquet will provides better performace with spark
- To explore all the supported file formats in spark. [Read official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources.html)

Comment: You're right, `collect` should be avoided. However, I would rather recommend writing in `parquet` than `csv`, but that's a detail

Comment: Yes, in spark processing parquet will gives better performance than csv. Just for an example i have specified csv. you can explore all other supported file formats from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources.html